# deleting a bunch of session with different names in c#

Tags: c#

I know how to delete session in c#

```
Session.Remove("SessionName");
```

How is that possible to delete all the sessions which conatin YYY in their name in c#?
for example

```
YYY_1
YYY_2 .....
```

Comment: It's not at all clear which sessions you are talking about. Please specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can delete all the `sessions` which contains `YYY` in it using this method:

```
List<string> keysToRemove = new List<string>();

foreach (var key in Session.Keys)
{
    if (key is string && key.ToString().Contains("YYY"))
    {
        keysToRemove.Add(key.ToString());
    }
}

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
{
    Session.Remove(key);
}
```

- Here we iterate over all session keys using Session.Keys.
- Here we check if each key is a string and contains the specified substring ("YYY").
- If a key matches the criteria, we add it to a list (keysToRemove).
- Finally, we iterate over the list of keys to remove and call Session.Remove for each key.

Ref : https://dotnetfiddle.net/SUGUqE

Answer (score -1):

U can use session Abondon

```
// Delete all sessions with the name "MySession".
string name = "YYY";

//Get all the sessions. You can do this by getting the 
//HttpSessionStateCollection from the Application object.
var sessions = Application["Sessions"] as HttpSessionStateCollection;

if (sessions != null)
{

    //Iterate over the sessions and check 
    //if the name of the session matches the name you want to delete.
    foreach (HttpSessionState session in sessions)
    {

        //If the name matches, delete the session 
        //using the Session.Abandon() method.
        if (session.SessionID.Contains(name))
        {
           session.Abandon();
        }
    }
}
```